# Comparing Unix timestamps

Tags: php

I need to compare two Unix timestamps and I'm having trouble with the math.  I know a Unix timestamp is the number of seconds since January 1, 1970.  But I'm doing something wrong with the math.  I'm trying to detect whether it has been 3 minutes from when the file was last modified.  Here is my code:

```
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    $filemodtime = filemtime($filename);
}

$three_min_from_now = mktime(0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0);

if (time() >= $filemodtime + $three_min_from_now) {
     // do stuff
} else {
     // do other stuff
}
```

But the else clause keeps being satisfied, not the if, even when the if should be true.  I think the issue is my math.  Can someone help?  Thanks.

Comment: Try printing out the values of your variables to make sure that you've set them correctly.

Comment: It's hard to tell because they're Unix timestamps.  The $three_min_from_now variable works correctly.  The $filemodtime correctly shows when the file was last modified.

Comment: Is time based on the time since 1/1/70?

Comment: Yes. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: Are you sure that $three_min_from_now is correct?

Comment: What you want to do is check whether `time >= modified time + 60 seconds`.

Comment: Yes, I ran the date function on it (date(H:i:s)) and I got back 0:01:00.

Comment: Don't worry about the 1 minutes vs. three minutes issue.  The Unix math is the larger issue

Comment: Please echo `$filemodtime`, `$three_min_from_now` and `time()` and take a look. They should just be numbers. Post here if you like.

Comment: Time: 14:29:45 File mod time + 3 min from now: 20:29:19 File mod time: 1340396899

Comment: Time: 14:30:30 File mod time + 3 min from now: 20:30:45 File mod time: 14:29:45

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$three_min_from_now = mktime(0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0);

if (time() >= $filemodtime + $three_min_from_now) {
```

What you're doing here is checking if time() is larger than the unix timestamp for the file modification, plus the unix timestamp for three minutes from now. It's very, very unlikely to be true - you're much better off just adding 180 to $filemodtime:

```
if (time() >= $filemodtime + (60 * 3)) {
```

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion would be to redo your if statement like this:

```
if((time() - $filemodtime) >= 180)
```

It removes the need to calculate expressly when '3 minutes from now' occurs

Answer (score 1):

```
if (file_exists($filename)) {
    $filemodtime = filemtime($filename);
}

if (time() - $filemodtime > (3*60)) {
     // it been more than 3 minutes
} else {
     // do other stuff
}
```

simply compare two integer timestamp values...