# Comparing unix timestamps in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

In PHP I have:

```
$diff = abs(strtotime(date('m/d/Y h:i:s')) - strtotime($latest));
$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
echo floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));
```

How do I get the difference in seconds? I've tried the following:

```
$diff = abs(strtotime(date('m/d/Y h:i:s')) - strtotime($latest));
```

Comment: Dupe of the search option on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Comparing+unix+timestamps+in+PHP+seconds&submit=search

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing Unix timestamps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11163529/comparing-unix-timestamps)

Answer (score 5):

Use `DateTime` instead, it will make your code much cleaner.

```
$latest = new DateTime($latest);
$now = new DateTime();

$diff = $latest->diff($now);
echo $diff->format('%y years %m months %d days');
```

Comment: I'm having problem with `DateTime`. Can you please look at this [program](http://ideone.com/xVGSoc)

Answer (score 2):

A timestamp is just a number of seconds from 01/01/1970. So its as simple as:

```
<?php
    $now = time();
    $latest = "21-11-2012 14:44";
    $latest = strtotime($latest);
    $diff = ($now - $latest);
    //$diff = Number of seconds difference between now and 21-11-2012 14:44
?>
```

Also take a look at the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class which has a lot more functionality when dealing with dates.

Comment: For some reason when I insert a field with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in MySQL then pull it out and compare it as &latest using your method I get 21586 seconds