# Laravel return status

Tags: php, laravel

I'm pretty new to laravel. And I feel like there's a better way to achieve the following logic of maintaining a status.

```
 public function getstatusAttribute ()
{
    $start = $this->start_date->format('Y-m-d');
    $end = $this->end_date->format('Y-m-d');
    $current_date = now()->toDateTimeString('Y-m-d');

    if ($end < $current_date) {
        return 'finished';
    } elseif ($start < $current_date && $current_date < $end) {
        return 'ongoing';
    } else {
        return 'pending';
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me out with this .

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Hirumina's answer, I would personally go with the Carbon PHP library.

If you don't want to use it, you can compare UNIX timestamps instead, like this:

```
public function getstatusAttribute ()
{
    $start = $this->start_date->format('U');
    $end = $this->end_date->format('U');
    $current_date = time();
    
    if ($end < $current_date) {
        return 'finished';
    } elseif ($start < $current_date && $current_date < $end) {
        return 'ongoing';
    }
    
    return 'pending';
}
```

References:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.time.php
- [Comparing unix timestamps in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13493482/comparing-unix-timestamps-in-php)
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php